# Woocommerce - different attribute per product size

Tags: wordpress, attributes, customization, woocommerce

Right, so I'm trying to setup a custom theme for woocommerce.

The site will have 1 products(Tyres)but multiple variations, different tyres.
I have it setup so that each tyre pattern is a product, each tyre can be part of a number of categories(Car, Bus, Truck) and also have a number an attribute(size, compound, Rating)etc.

Know I need each different size tyre to have is own unique attributes. So the user could look at tyre1 which comes in 3 sizes. then there would be a dropdown menu to select the size. this would then list out the other attributes for the size selects. can anyone help me try work how best to accomplish this?

This is an example of something similar [link](http://www.firestonetrucktires.com/tires#New) can I accomplish this with woocommerce?

thank for your time.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a "variable product". When you create a new product or editing some already created, take a look where it says "product type", choose a variable, then select all the attributes that product will have under Attributes tab, then go to Variations tab and chose those variations you wish to be available for the product. This will add a select box that let you do exactly what you asked.

See:

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-variations/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qOmOIxpjDw

Comment: Thanks so much for your input, I have been looking into variable products and It does seem to be a the functionality I'm looking for apar from the variation options. My products dont need fields for (weight, dimensions)etc I need things like Classification, Rating, Patten type etc. Any Ideas if I can still use the variation functions for this? thanks dude

Comment: On woocommerce->settings->catalog, you will find some checkboxes to choose if use or not use dimensions, etc. Then on product->attributes, you can add Classification, Rating, etc, and there add some terms for each one, then on product this will be variations as mentioned. If you find my anser was the one you need to resolve your doubt, don´t forget to upvote, just click the up arrow on the left! :)

Comment: Hmm this seems like a clunky solution to me sorry, If i do variable products like this it shows all the options as dropdowns. I just want size as a variable option and then each size has different attributes. that when the user selects the size it changes the attributes for that size.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the results I required using 'Advanced Custom Fields' for variations then passing the SKU as an ID to change the other attributes. thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Well... Seems like you need a custom work in there. You need to know how to code wp and woo, if not, may be a plugin or someone freelance to take a look and create what you need.

Comment: This doesn't help answer the question of how to do this.

Comment: I've provided two long answers trying to solve the question. This is also an old post. You didn't provide help with your post... At all.